# Is having a function in local state of component bad practice?

Tags: reactjs

Is there anything wrong with setting a function in the local state of your component and using it later?

A possible use case for this would be where I have a modal component, I use a state management library as redux. When opening the modal I want to give it a callback function for when the user clicks on "Ok". See codesandbox for an example implementation.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kxoxq5jz0v

Comment: In your example I don't get why the function is in the state and defined at a later stage. Why not just define it to start with? In general I'd keep data in the state and functions as component properties. And make functions declarations explicit and their input/output as fixed as possible. If you want to do any behavioural changes, handle it *within* the logic of the function. Having a function in a variable and reassigning it seems like a good way to create weird behaviour and hard to track issues down the line if you're not super careful

Comment: I agree, there are cases however (such as a modal) where the code becomes more readable when giving the function as a prop to the component.

Comment: I still don't quite get what you mean, whether you define the function in the state or as a component function, it'll be passed to the modal as a prop in the exact same fashion either way. I don't get how one is more readable than the other, maybe I'm missing something. Either way, doing risky stuff for readability usually isn't a good trade in the long run.

Comment: Just declare and write your class function and pass it as props. You don't need to set it to null first and then change it later.